# django with postgresql - trying to connect heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

i'm trying to connect my django app to the heroku free databse.

i downloaded psycopg2 via pip.

my setting file is:

```
import psycopg2
DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'name',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'host name',   
    'PORT': 'xxxx', 
    }
}
```

i ran the local server (i.e. manage.py runserver) to see if i can really connect to heroku database but i get the following error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'CTFdj.settings' (Is it on sys.path?          
Is there an import error in the settings file?): DLL load failed: 
The specified module could not be found.
```

can someone help me figure out what the problem is?
thank you

Comment: post your proc file. Are you using singe settings file?

Comment: i am using a single settings file. my proc file is:  web: gunicorn project.wsgi --log-file     (but it doesn't work even on the local host..)